# How to merge different google analytics properties in one jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have a google analytics account with seven different properties, each properties is a different domain, but everyone goes to one site only.

**example domains:**

```
 example1.com 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1',
 examplee.org 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2',
 example2.com 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3',
 examp.org    'UA-XXXXXXXX-4',
 exxample.net 'UA-XXXXXXXX-5'
```

and so on...

How can I merge my seven domain, so my account considered them all together, but in one `ga.js` code.

Comment: You could look at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite?hl=nl

Comment: Thanks, so can I use ? 

<pre>
var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']); _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example1.com']); _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'examplee.org']); _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example2.com']); _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'examp.org']); _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]); 
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</pre>

Comment: Look at the section "Tracking Across Multiple Domains and Sub-domains". The javascript for your analytics part differs on each domain. So on example1.com you use _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', example1.org]); and on example2.com you use _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', example2.org]);

Comment: Yes, but it is correct to write this way,because I want my track ID to be only one.
I read this link "https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en&ref_topic=2772342"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Google Analytics script on each domain. Use this on example1.com:

```
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example1.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

.. and this on example2.com:

```
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example2.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

A little piece of advice: if you use the exact same content on example1.com and example2.com, it would be wise to simply 301 redirect example2.com to example1.com (or vice versa).

Comment: Yes, the content is the same. Thanks, I will read more about 301 redirect

Comment: When you do a 301 redirect, you won't have any duplicate content issues.